# Material Design Lite - Cards of different height in grid

Tags: material-design-lite

After some advice really, I cant seem to find any information about how to do this and cant figure it out from trying many scenarios in code.

I want two columns split 8 and 4. (consider this for desktop for now)

The 8-wide column will have full-width cards as will the 4. However, no matter what I do, the taller of the cards causes the other column to match the height. How do I stop this so I can have different height cards which dont cause other content to match the tallest height?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have this:

```
.mdl-grid
  .mdl-card.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--3-col.mdl-cell--4-col-tablet.mdl-shadow--2dp
    %figure.mdl-card__media
      = image_tag "prequelle.jpg"  
    .mdl-card__title
      %h2.mdl-card__title-text
        Welcome to Hell
    .mdl-card__supporting-text  
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...            
    .mdl-card__actions.mdl-card--border
      %a.mdl-button.mdl-button--colored.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect Read More
      .mdl-layout-spacer
      %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
        %i.material-icons favorite
      %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
        %i.material-icons share

  .mdl-card.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--3-col.mdl-cell--4-col-tablet.mdl-shadow--2dp
    %figure.mdl-card__media
      = image_tag "bg_map1.png"  
    .mdl-card__title
      %h2.mdl-card__title-text
        Welcome to Hell
    .mdl-card__supporting-text  
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...            
    .mdl-card__actions.mdl-card--border
      %a.mdl-button.mdl-button--colored.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect Read More
      .mdl-layout-spacer
      %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
        %i.material-icons favorite
      %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
        %i.material-icons share
```

Then your cards will all be the same height.

You have to move the `mdl-card` **inside** the `mdl-cell` class

So, do this to get different heights:

```
.mdl-grid
  .mdl-card.mdl-cell.mdl-cell--3-col.mdl-cell--4-col-tablet.mdl-shadow--2dp
    %figure.mdl-card__media
      = image_tag "prequelle.jpg"  
    .mdl-card__title
      %h2.mdl-card__title-text
        Welcome to Hell
    .mdl-card__supporting-text  
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...            
    .mdl-card__actions.mdl-card--border
      %a.mdl-button.mdl-button--colored.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect Read More
      .mdl-layout-spacer
      %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
        %i.material-icons favorite
      %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
        %i.material-icons share

  .mdl-cell.mdl-cell--3-col.mdl-cell--4-col-tablet
    .mdl-card.mdl-shadow--2dp
      %figure.mdl-card__media
        = image_tag "bg_map1.png"  
      .mdl-card__title
        %h2.mdl-card__title-text
          Welcome to Hell
      .mdl-card__supporting-text  
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...            
      .mdl-card__actions.mdl-card--border
        %a.mdl-button.mdl-button--colored.mdl-js-button.mdl-js-ripple-effect Read More
        .mdl-layout-spacer
        %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
          %i.material-icons favorite
        %button.mdl-button.mdl-button--icon.mdl-button--colored
          %i.material-icons share
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found the content-grid class which I wasn't using. Working as I want it to now.

Comment: How did you use content-grid class to resolve your auto height issue?